# Can I transform Skinshifter twice in one turn?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say that you have [Skinshifter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Skinshifter) in play and your opponent attacks with a 3/3 token. You choose to block with Skinshifter and in response to the block, transform him into a 4/4 rhino creature with trample. Then your opponent (in response to you transforming Skinshifter) plays Magma Jet and targets the now transformed Skinshifter. Can you transform Skinshifter a second time provided you have the mana?

Comment: With regard to *"targets the now transformed Skinshifter"* - You seem to have some confusion about what it means to "respond to" something. When your opponent responds to Skinshifter's activated ability, it has *not* transformed yet. It dies to Magma Jet, and *then* the ability resolves, but Skinshifter is dead now, so nothing happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. the last line of the ability literally states: "Active this ability only once each turn"

Answer (score -1):

Actually, with Rings of Brighthearth, you can manage to transform Skinshifter twice in one turn. (But do note that you can't change modes on the copied ability.)

Comment: Whilst that's technically true, it won't help the asker do what they're trying to do.